# Select rows for which at least one row per set meets a condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have following table:

```
create table test (
  company_id integer not null, 
  client_id integer not null, 
  client_status text,
  unique (company_id, client_id)
);

insert into test values
  (1, 1, 'y'),    -- company1

  (2, 2, null),   -- company2

  (3, 3, 'n'),    -- company3

  (4, 4, 'y'),    -- company4
  (4, 5, 'n'),

  (5, 6, null),   -- company5
  (5, 7, 'n')
;
```

Basically, there are 5 different companies, each one has one or more clients and each client has status: 'y' or 'n' (might be null as well).

What I have to do is to select all pairs `(company_id, client_id)` for all companies for which there is at least one client whose status is not 'n' ('y' or null). So for the example data above, the output should be:

```
company_id;client_id
1;1
2;2
4;4
4;5
5;6
5;7
```

I tried something with window functions but I can't figure out how to compare the number of ALL clients with the number of clients with `STATUS = 'n'`.

```
select company_id,
count(*) over (partition by company_id) as all_clients_count
from test
-- where all_clients_count != ... ?
```

I figured out how to do this, but I am not sure if it's the right way:

```
select sub.company_id, unnest(sub.client_ids)
from (
  select company_id, array_agg(client_id) as client_ids
  from test
  group by company_id
  having count(*) != count( (case when client_status = 'n' then 1 else null end) )
) sub
```

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Do you need to select the companyids and clientids or just the companyids?

Comment: You're right, sorry for that, I updated question (expected result). When at least one client in company has status null or status != 'n' then I want to get this company along with all clients, even with status = 'n'. In other words I want to filter out all companies (along with clients) for which all clients have status = 'n'.

Comment: Important missing detail: Thee is no `UNIQUE` constraint on `(company_id,  client_id)` in your table definition. But your test data make it seem like `(company_id,  client_id)` is, in fact, unique. Is it? If not, do you need * all* qualifying rows, or each combination of `company_id` and `client_id` just *once*?

Comment: Yes, you are right, (company_id, client_id) is unique.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter sorry, I ended up using my (last one in question) solution because for now it works quite well for me. Anyway I will accept your answer as I am pretty sure it's correct and most complete :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Basically* you are looking for the expression:

```
client_status IS DISTINCT FROM 'n'
```

The column `client_status` should really be data type [**`boolean`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html), not `text`, which would allow the simpler expression:

```
client_status IS NOT FALSE
```

The manual has details in the chapter [**Comparison Operators**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).

---

Assuming your actual table has a [`UNIQUE` or `PK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html), we arrive at:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  company_id    integer NOT NULL, 
  client_id     integer NOT NULL, 
  client_status boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY (company_id, client_id)
);
```

#### Queries

All of these do the same (what you asked), which is the fastest depends on data distribution:

```
SELECT company_id, client_id
FROM   test t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM test
   WHERE  company_id = t.company_id
   AND    client_status IS NOT FALSE
   );
```

Or:

```
SELECT company_id, client_id
FROM   test t
JOIN  (
   SELECT company_id
   FROM   test t
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING bool_or(client_status IS NOT FALSE)
   ) c USING (company_id);
```

Or:

```
SELECT company_id, client_id
FROM   test t
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT company_id, client_status 
   FROM   test t
   ORDER  BY company_id, client_status DESC
   ) c USING (company_id)
WHERE  c.client_status IS NOT FALSE;
```

Boolean values sort `FALSE` -> `TRUE` -> `NULL` in ascending sort order. So  `FALSE` comes last in descending order. If there's is *any* other value available, then that one's picked first ...

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892611/939860)

The added PK is implemented with a useful index for these queries. If you want faster, yet, add a partial index for query 1:

```
CREATE INDEX test_special_idx ON test (company_id, client_id)
WHERE  client_status IS NOT FALSE;
```

You *could* use window functions, too, but that would be slower. Example with `first_value()`:

```
SELECT company_id, client_id
FROM  (
   SELECT company_id, client_id
        , first_value(client_status) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id
                                           ORDER BY client_status DESC) AS stat
   FROM   test t
   ) sub
WHERE  stat IS NOT FALSE;
```

For *lots* of rows per `company_id`, one of these techniques may be faster, still:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be simplified a bit:

```
select company_id 
from test 
group by company_id 
having count(*) filter (where client_status!='n' or client_status is null) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood you but I imagine something like:

```
 select * 
 from test x 
 where exists ( 
     select 1 
     from test y 
     where x.company_id = y.company_id 
       and coalesce(client_status, 'y') <> 'n'
 );
```

will work. coalesce is use to map null to 'y', but anything different than 'n' should do

Using an OLAP function can save us a "join":

```
select company_id, client_id 
from (
    select x.*
         , count(nullif(coalesce(client_status,'y'),'n')) 
               over (partition by company_id) as cnt 
    from test x
) 
where cnt > 0;
```

Here we map null -> 'y' and 'n' -> null. Since count(x) will count rows where x is not null, we count rows where client_status <> 'n'. I used an OLAP function to avoid GROUP BY, which means that we only need to reference the table once.

Answer (score 0):

A standard SQL query below should work

```
select
  company_id,
  client_id
from test
where client_status!='n' or client_status is null;
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I did not write question (expected result) precisely: when at least one client in company has status null or status != 'n' then I want to get this company along with all clients, even with status = 'n'.