# “Column does not exist” with INNER JOIN and MAX query in ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, order-by

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 with ActiveRecord. I'm trying to get all customers sorted by a specific provider. The relationship between models is: customer has many orders, which belong to a provider.

What I want to achieve is something like:

Example data:

```
customer1 <- order1 -> provider1
customer2 <- order2 -> provider2
customer3 <- order3 -> provider3
```

Expecting result:

```
query_for_provider(2) => customer2, customer1, customer3 
query_for_provider(1) => customer1, customer2, customer3 
query_for_provider(3) => customer3, customer1, customer2
```

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT "customers".*, MAX(providers.id) AS provider_id FROM "customers"
INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."patient_id" = "customers"."id"
INNER JOIN "providers" ON "providers"."id" = "orders"."provider_id"
GROUP BY customers.id
ORDER BY @(2 - provider_id);
```

Unfortunately, it returns an error:

> ```
> column "provider_id" doesn't exist
> ```

When I wrap this with `SELECT * FROM` (as below) it works, but in this case, can't use this with ActiveRecord, which requires `SELECT ... FROM customers` construction.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT "customers".*, MAX(providers.id) AS provider_id FROM "customers"
  INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."patient_id" = "customers"."id"
  INNER JOIN "providers" ON "providers"."id" = "orders"."provider_id"
  GROUP BY customers.id
) AS customers_with_provider
ORDER BY @(2 - provider_id);
```

Any thoughts how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for, but I've generated next example:

```
create table customers
(
    id int not null primary key, 
    name text not null
);

create table providers
(
    id int not null primary key, 
    name text not null
);

create table orders
(
    id int not null primary key,
    provider_id int not null,
    patient_id int not null,
    constraint fk_customers foreign key (patient_id) references customers (id),
    constraint fk_providers foreign key (provider_id) references providers (id)
);
```

And I've added some data:

```
insert into customers values
(1, 'cust 1'),
(2, 'cust 2'),
(3, 'cust 3');

insert into providers values
(1, 'prov 1'),
(2, 'prov 2'),
(3, 'prov 3');

insert into orders values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 2, 2),
(4, 3, 2);
```

Now, simply replace `order by @(2 - provider_id)` by `order by @(2 - max(o.provider_id))` and it works.

```
select   c.*, max(o.provider_id) as max_prov
from     orders o
join     customers c
on       o.patient_id = c.id
join     providers p
on       o.provider_id = p.id
group by c.id
order by @(2 - max(o.provider_id));
```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1417b05bffe93c197143aea6fb9a5c80)*</kbd>

BTW: Why are you using this syntax: `@(2 - provider_id)` You are subtracting from a constant value.

Comment: Thank you so much @McNets! That's I was looking for!

`@(2 - provider_id)` -  2 here was a sample provider_id I wanted to order by.

Answer (score 1):

To sort a given `provider_id` first, this is cheaper:

```
SELECT c.*, MAX(o.provider_id) AS provider_id
FROM   customers c
JOIN   orders    o ON o.patient_id = c.id
GROUP  BY c.id
ORDER  BY MAX(o.provider_id) <> 2        -- to list provider_id 2 first
        , MAX(o.provider_id);            -- to sort the rest ascending
```

Works because `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`.
Add `provider_id` as 2nd `ORDER BY` item to sort the rest in ascending order.
(`NULL` sorts last in ascending order in any case.)

Note that ***your original expression*** `@(2 - provider_id)` *also* affects the sort of the rest since it folds values above and below the given `provider_id`. Makes it impossible to sort the rest in ascending order like you requested - and is therefore ***wrong on principal***.

Assuming that referential integrity is enforced by a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to `providers` (the typical setup), you don't need to include that table in the query at all. Faster.

Related:

- [Select rows for which at least one row per set meets a condition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139980/select-rows-for-which-at-least-one-row-per-set-meets-a-condition/140070#140070)
- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)

***If*** that involves most or all of table `orders` it's faster to aggregate first and join later:

```
SELECT c.*, o.provider_id
FROM   customers c
JOIN  (
   SELECT patient_id, MAX(provider_id) AS provider_id
   FROM   orders
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) o ON o.patient_id = c.id
ORDER  BY o.provider_id <> 2, o.provider_id;
```

#### Why the error?

> ```
> column "provider_id" doesn't exist
> ```

You tried to reference the ***output*** column name `provider_id` in the expression `@(2 - provider_id)` But expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause can only be formed from ***input*** columns. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each *`expression`* can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (`SELECT` list item), or it can be an arbitrary **expression formed from input-column values**.

Bold emphasis mine. Postgres couldn't find `provider_id` in the list of *input* column names and responded with the error you quoted.

Comment: Thank you @Erwin, that's very instructive answer! It's awesome to learn something new and know what was the problem. Thanks :)